# Rich Text Box *Formatting

Tags: text, colors, formatting

Language: C#

**My Question...**

Q. Is there a SIMPLE way to change the format of strings in the rich text box, similar the way you handle it with HTML.

*For example:*

```
richTextBox1.text = "[i]Hello[/i] [Bold]world![/Bold]";
```

output: *Hello* **World!**

I am also wondering if there is colour?

With kind regards and thank in advance for your feedback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rich Text Format is a language in and of itself.  However, you don't need to learn it to use it.

However, there are other ways this can be accomplished that might be more practical, like so:

```
RichTextBox1.Text = "Hello World"

' Select Hello and Bold It
RichTextBox1.Find("Hello")
Dim fntBold As New Font(RichTextBox1.Font, FontStyle.Bold)
RichTextBox1.SelectionFont = fntBold

' Select World and Set to Italics
RichTextBox1.Find("World")
Dim fntItalic As New Font(RichTextBox1.Font, FontStyle.Italic)
RichTextBox1.SelectionFont = fntItalic
```

Afterwards, if you are curious, you can look at RichTextBox.Rtf property (it's a string) to see what it looks like.  This is what I saw after I did it:

```
{\rtf1\ansi\deff0{\fonttbl{\f0\fnil\fcharset0 Microsoft Sans Serif;}}\viewkind4\uc1\pard\lang1033\b\f0\fs17 Hello\b0  \i World\i0\par}
```

In fact, if you then take that text, open Notepad, copy the Rtf property's text, save as an RTF file.  Close down Notepad and open the RTF in Word, you'll see this same same text with the same look and feel.

Answer (score 0):

Hi and thank's so much **@Ctznkane525**, thanks for putting me on the right track, I did convert it to C# and this is the outcome:

```
using System.Drawing.Text;

        rtb_Main.Text = "Hello World";
        rtb_Main.Find("Hello");
        Font fntBold = new Font(FontFamily.GenericSansSerif, 14.0F, FontStyle.Bold);
        rtb_Main.SelectionFont = fntBold;

        rtb_Main.Find("World");
        Font fntItalic = new Font(FontFamily.GenericSansSerif, 14.0F, FontStyle.Italic);
        rtb_Main.SelectionFont = fntItalic;
```